# Add function to variable number of links onclick events

Tags: jquery, html, image, frontend

I have a bit of JQuery and javascrip to change a large image's src attribute with the src of a smaller thumbnail. There are a varying number of thumbnails, depending on what images are uploaded.

The code I have below works when clicking the thumbnail, but to create the onclick event for each thumbnail I am having to loop through each photo in the list and write out a "$('#thumb_n').click(function()..." for each thumbnail.

Is there a simpler way to do this please?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumb_1').click(function(){
        changeImgSrc($('#detailImage'), "/images/photos/1/small/draughtDesign_01.jpg");
    });
    $('#thumb_4').click(function(){
        changeImgSrc($('#detailImage'), "/images/photos/1/small/draughtDesign_02.jpg");
    });
    $('#thumb_5').click(function(){
        changeImgSrc($('#detailImage'), "/images/photos/1/small/draughtDesign_03.jpg");
    });
});

function changeImgSrc(targetImg, sourceMSallImgURL){
    var thbSource = sourceMSallImgURL;
    var lrgSource = thbSource.replace('/small/', '/large/');
    targetImg.attr("src", lrgSource);
}
</script>

<div class="galleryPhotos">
                <span class="galleryPic shadow"><img src="/images/photos/1/large/draughtDesign_01.jpg" id="detailImage" width="515" height="380" alt="photo description 1" /></span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript: return false;" title="photo description 1"><img src="/images/photos/1/small/draughtDesign_01.jpg" width="160" height="115" id="thumb_1" alt="photo description 1" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript: return false;" title="photo description 2"><img src="/images/photos/1/small/draughtDesign_02.jpg" width="160" height="115" id="thumb_4" alt="photo description 2" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript: return false;" title="photo description 3"><img src="/images/photos/1/small/draughtDesign_03.jpg" width="160" height="115" id="thumb_5" alt="photo description 3" /></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: did you get it working with my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('.galleryPhotos ul li a img').click(function(){
    changeImgSrc($('#detailImage'), $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Or add a class (for example `thumbImages`) to all images in `<li>` tag and then

```
$('.thumbImages').click(function(){
    changeImgSrc($('#detailImage'), $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: Welcome... Happy to be Helpful.. :)

Answer (score 0):

add class "thum_Img" to each of your thumbnail image tag like this.

```
<img src="/images/photos/1/small/draughtDesign_01.jpg" width="160" height="115" id="thumb_1" alt="photo description 1" class="thum_Img"/>
```

and do the following...

```
$('.thumb_Img').click(function(){
        changeImgSrc($('#detailImage'), $(this).attr("src"));
    });
```